# Jquery file support in Eclipse Multi-page Editor plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am facing the issue on Multi-page editor plugin development. I want this plugin to support jquery. It is supporting

Javascript functions using import "sun.org.mozilla.javascrip". But it is not supporting Jquery functions.

I am calling Jquery file for some text convertion using jquery code when opening perview mode in Multi-page editor. But the following error throws.

```
**Code:**

BufferedReader script = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mapBuilder.js"));         
Context context = Context.enter();      
ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();      
context.evaluateReader(scope, script, "script", 1, null);      
Function fct = (Function)scope.get("buildMap", scope);       
String editorText = editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editor.getEditorInput()).get();       
Object result = fct.call(context, scope, scope, new Object[] {editorText});       
text.setText(result.toString());        

**Error i got:**
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (script#18)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance